# How to count value of matching with the field value in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mlab

**I have a document in which perform 2 task.**

I am new in mongoDB ,These tasks are very small and trying to explain.

> 1. To calculate number of users which have values of start hour, start Min, and start Sec these values should be less than or equal to  start_min, start_hour which is defined in dObject.***(We have to calculate number of users which come in an organisation ("orgId") earlier or at on time, Users have startHour,startMin and startSec this  values should be equal or less than values which are  defined in dObject Data (start_hour 10 and start_min 0) ).***
> 2. To calculate number of users which have values of start hour, start Min, and start Sec these values should be greater to start_min, start_hour which is defined in dObject.***(We have to calculate number of users which come in an organisation ("orgId") late Users have startHour,startMin and startSec this  values should be greater than values which are  defined in dObject Data (start_hour 10 and start_min 0) ).***

***NOTE***
consider end_sec and start_sec with zero(0) in dObject Data. and keeping in mind organization Id and shiftId should be unique(By grouping).

**MongoDB Document is give below.**

```
{
  "_id" : {
       "orgId" : "af39bc69-1938-4149-b9f7-f101fd9baf73",
       "userId" : "68c88420-4c22-11e7-ad9f-e5d77ee44b6c",
       "checkinShiftId" : "7803421a-a680-4173-99af-a55c6f211724"
   },
  "lastSeen" : ISODate("2018-01-19T16:44:47.467+05:30"),
  "firstSeen" : ISODate("2018-01-19T10:27:44.217+05:30"),
  "dObjectInformation" : [ ],
  "startHour" : 10,
  "startMin" : 27,
  "startSec" : 44,
  "lastHour" : 16,
  "lastMin" : 44,
  "lastSec" : 47
},
{
  "_id" : {
       "orgId" : "af39bc69-1938-4149-b9f7-f101fd9baf73",
       "userId" : "5cce5410-dca1-11e6-a87c-29432312f160",
       "checkinShiftId" : "7803421a-a680-4173-99af-a55c6f211724"
   },
  "lastSeen" : ISODate("2018-01-19T20:32:50.041+05:30"),
  "firstSeen" : ISODate("2018-01-19T11:05:10.095+05:30"),
  "dObjectInformation" : [
    {
        "_id" : "5de84f30-6c62-11e7-9a37-dfd3a80c2c8c",
        "dObjectData" : {
            "end_min" : "0",
            "end_hour" : "19",
            "start_min" : "0",
            "start_hour" : "10",
            "dObjectId" : "7803421a-a680-4173-99af-a55c6f211724",
            "objectName" : "shift",
            "objectId" : "5a6ecc6a-1d71-4400-adc6-2eb3b39cb5d0",
            "updatedOn" : ISODate("2018-01-16T17:48:22.990+05:30"),
            "addedOn" : ISODate("2017-07-19T14:42:19.620+05:30")
        }
    }
],
 "startHour" : 11,
 "startMin" : 5,
 "startSec" : 10,
 "lastHour" : 20,
 "lastMin" : 32,
 "lastSec" : 50
}
```

**Expected Result**

```
 {
   "shiftId":"avc",
   "orgId":"2323"
   "numberOfUserReachBeforeOrEqualOnTime":"12",
   "numberOfUserReachAfterOnTime":"4" 
 }
```

Please suggest me how to use aggregate Query.Thanks!

Comment: Is this part of larger aggregation query ? Is it just a comparison between embedded documents fields and top level fields ?

Comment: Yes! It is just a comparison between embedded documents  and top level fields.

Comment: You can use `$group` with `$sum` that takes `$cond` operator which will check the logic you mentioned in the post and output 0 and 1.

Comment: @Veeram! Thanks for suggestion.Plz help me how to use    $group with $sum and $cond operator. I am stuck  when apply these opertors. Plz can  you share how to apply on this ..I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Np. Why are date time properties string values inside db object ? What values do you consider for comparison  when dbobject is empty array ? Do you take first set of values for dbobject when it is not a single value array ?

Comment: @Veeram.. The date time properties string values inside db object which are showing only on front side(web site).we can skip comparison when dobject is empty array and Yes it always single value array of dobject... Thanks!